# How to find sub-strings of a data string in korn-shell by their label

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a data string that contains multiple properties in the following format:
PNO25|DNO9|NWT153|NAM579|NPC3|

So the properties are PNO, DNO, NWT, NAM, NPC

Note that the properties are not always in the same order and the values may have varying lengths (i.e. where I have DNO9 above the value of DNO is 9 but it could come as DNO23 or DNO152 where the values would be 23 or 152 respectively)

I need to be able to retrieve the values for the properties from this data string.

What would be the best approach to pulling the value of any property from this data string in a korn shell script? For simplicity sake lets just retrieve the value of DNO.

I am not an experienced shell programmer... and I am at my wits end here having tried my best Googling korn-shell, using awk, grep etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just to extract one tag value, you can try this

```
$ awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(match($i,/^DNO/)) {sub(/DNO/,"",$i); print $i}}' file

9
```

to get a dictionary like output of name:value pairs, perhaps this is easier...

```
$ tr '|' '\n' <file | 
  sed -r 's/([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)/\1:\2/g;/^$/d' | 
  sort

DNO:9
NAM:579
NPC:3
NWT:153
PNO:25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export them in shell variables with

```
string="PNO25|DNO9|NWT153|NAM579|NPC3PNO25|DNO9|NWT153|NAM579|NPC3"
export $(echo "${string}" | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)/=\1/g; s/|/ /g')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS='|' 'sub(/^DNO/,"")' file
9

$ awk -v RS='|' 'sub(/^NWT/,"")' file
153
```

or if you have the target name in a shell variable:

```
$ tgt="NAM"; awk -v RS='|' -v tgt="$tgt" 'sub("^"tgt,"")' file
579

$ tgt="NAM"; val=$(awk -v RS='|' -v tgt="$tgt" 'sub("^"tgt,"")' file); echo "$val"
579
```